# Security for String immutability

Tags: java

Im trying to understand how String immutability increases the security. I had searched and found many cases but it does not give real practical example.

Here is one such example -

```
boolean connect(string s){
    if (!isSecure(s)) { 
        throw new SecurityException(); 
    }
    //here will cause problem, if s is changed before this by using other references.    
    causeProblem(s);
}
```

In the above case the connect method could be called with any valid String

For ex:- connect("DB2") or connect("ORACLE") and the method will be executed accordingly.

Can someone elaborate more on this how the security is enhanced?

Excuse if its more basic question.

Comment: What gave you the impression that `String` immutability increases security?

Comment: Here is one such blog :- http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-string-immutable-java

Comment: Here is one more in SO- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274874/how-does-java-string-being-immutable-increase-security

Comment: That is *performance*; not *security*.

Comment: This question should not be marked as duplicate..I read the SO question but could not understand "Were String mutable, this would lead to a subtle exploit: an attacker would pass a good URL, wait for a few microseconds, and then set the URL to point to an attack site."

Comment: This question is totally a duplicate, and I think entirely based on a flawed premise. `StringBuilder` is a mutable character structure. So Java does have them. The reason `String` is immutable is performance related.

Comment: and its not security related, Correct?

Comment: Read the answer below. If there are security benefits, they're tangential. Again, `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder`. Not to mention there are hacks with reflection to modify `String`(s).

Answer (score 0):

There are also caveats in the opposite direction, for example some API avoid using `String` for passwords and prefer `char[]` (which can be erased in memory immediately after use, whereas a String may stick around for quite a while).